# PR2 tabletop manipulation

Tags: gazebo, moveit, tabletop, pick-and-place, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to create a setup in which a PR2 robot, in Gazebo, would be picking objects from a table, manipulating them and placing them back.

There is a package pr2_tabletop_manipulation that supposedly demoes such a thing but it seems to be not supported for a long time now. And it is unclear to me how it works.
I also tried to use MoveIt to setup a tabletop scene but also got stuck at some point.

So my questions are:

1. What would the modern setup to achieve that goal?
2. Should I try to use Kinetic or is it better to go back to Fuerte and try using the old packages?
3. Should I be using MoveIt for my problem?
4. Does anybody have a working example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255390/pr2-tabletop-manipulation/) by [lubiluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29460/lubiluk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 packages are not in a very good shape at the moment (things work partially in indigo, but it's worse for kinetic).
I suppose, but don't know for sure, that it would take some work to get `pr2_tabletop_manipulation` to work on either release.
Personally, I don't think we will see a tabletop manipulation package *exclusively for the pr2* again.
But I'm not aware of an equivalent package for more general use at the moment.

In my very personal opinion, fuerte is dead and everyone should just work with more current platforms.
In most cases there is at least an equal amount of work associated with maintaining a fuerte system compared to upgrading/rewriting setups in current releases.

The moveit side of tabletop scene manipulation works pretty well at the moment.
[The standard MoveIt tutorial for the MoveGroupInterface](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html) is probably a good first reference.
MoveIt's manipulation pipeline to pick objects can be setup to work too. (I have a working example with a UR5 arm [here](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/tams_ur5_pick_place))

I don't know about the Gazebo side of things.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lubiluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29460/lubiluk/) on 2017-02-23**:
Thank you. I will check out UR5, I think it may be a viable alternative to PR2 in my case.